# Getting old data in React form on doing OnChange

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an object and a note field as states in the React component. When users enter a note I change the note state and add it to my object. But I am getting the wrong input in my object. 
If I enter "hello" in the note field, "hell" get added to the object and the object becomes {note: "hell"}

```
const SelectedSymptom = () => {
    const [note, setNote] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
        const update = async () => {
            await setSelectedSymptom((prev) => {
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    feature: feature,
                    since: since,
                    severity: severity,
                    place: place,
                    colour: colour,
                    note: note,
                };
            });
        };
        update();
        console.log(selected);
    }, [since, feature, severity, place, colour, note]);

    return (<div>
            <label for="Note">Note</label>
            <textarea
                style={{ border: "1px solid", borderRadius: "5px", padding: "5px" }}
                id="Note"
                name="Note"
                rows="3"
                cols="auto"
                value={note}
                placeholder="Enter note here"
                onChange={(e) => setNote(e.target.value)}
            ></textarea> </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Did you actually check the content of your object? As you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-sid-yi0jz?file=/src/App.js) the `note` always up-to-date inside `useEffect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update is an async function (so I assume you have async operations in there, more than just setSelectedSymptom );

if you put console.log(selected) after update(), you are just logging previous value, because the console.log is executed before update() is finished.

Just move console.log(select) to outside useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const update = async () => {
            await setSelectedSymptom((prev) => {
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    feature: feature,
                    since: since,
                    severity: severity,
                    place: place,
                    colour: colour,
                    note: note,
                };
            });
        };
        update();
     
    }, [since, feature, severity, place, colour, note]);

   console.log(selected);
```